# What to analyze and mine in news articles?

Tags: data-analysis, text-analysis

I am trying to learn some text analysis and intend to apply the same in news articles which i download and persist in an relational database against the url,keywords,start date, end date,headline and description.

Except that I don't know what to analyze and what are the practical use cases of such an analysis ?

Comment: Hi, SO is a good resource for solving specific and verifiable problems, so primarily opinion-based, broad or unclear questions are out of scope. If you have an in-scope question, please feel free to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as another question.

Comment: @jpp- Before I put up this question, I knew I was going to be downvoted. Problem is google search gives references and not directions, if I intend to learn something new where should I put those questions, your comments are valid as per the rules to be followed but its disheartening to not get an answer just because the question may not fit perfectly in the periphery of rules.

Comment: Don't worry about downvoting (there, that's corrected). The problem is nowadays you don't get good *answers* to these questions because they are so opinion-based. SO has decided as a whole they aren't as useful and liable to just opinionating.. I hope that makes sense. If you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50074701/edit) with some context, e.g. a *practical example* with data, a specific programming language, what you've tried, etc, you'll probably have more luck.